# Simple question on definition of Stieltjes Function of Measure on Real Numbers

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In this [link](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Stieltjes_Function_of_Measure_on_Real_Numbers), I'm not sure how to understand the meaning of the $..$ in the definition of the Stieltjes function of measure $\mu$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Folland's *Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications* (pg. 35) the Stieltjes function is defined as:
\begin{equation}
F(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\mu((0,x]) &\mbox{if } x>0\\
0 &\mbox{if } x=0\\
-\mu((x,0]) &\mbox{if } x<0\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

The notation in the article just represents an interval, replacing (for example) $(0,x]$ with $(0. .x]$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One question, though. According to this definition, $ F(-\infty)= $ ? I thought F could be seen as the cumulative distribution function when we're dealing with a probability measure... but if the measure gives a positive to $(-\infty,0]$, I don't see how $\mu$ can be seen as a probability measure...